# Travelling Requirements to Schengen Countries using Romanian Visa for Non-European Citizen

Tags: visas, schengen, romania

I am a student on Exchange studies to Romania. Is it difficult to obtain a visa for Schengen countries with Romanian visa? I want to travel to other EU parts during my stay in Romania. Romanian visa duration: 10 months.
What procedures exists and how long does it take?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Answer (score 1):

The Romanian visa does not make much difference, except perhaps in allowing you to lodge your visa application in a consulate in Romania instead of your country of origin. You will still need to fulfil all the requirements of a regular Schengen visa.

Also, being a resident of a rich country like the US or UK would seem to bolster your credibility as a visitor but I am not sure that what is essentially a temporary status in one of the poorest countries in the EU really helps all that much (even if I suspect that nobody would say that officially).

Comment: Thank you for responding....So do I need to process for Schengen VISA if I want to enter schengen countries? how long does it take?

Comment: @Visitor It depends, between a few days and a few weeks usually, a month or two in the worse case.

Comment: What is the procedure to apply for the Schengen VISA? and what about the validity of the VISA, how long is it valid for?

Comment: @Visitor A Schengen visa can have a validity ranging between a few days and five years, depending on your situation and the evidence you submit with the application. You cannot in any case stay more than 90 days at once, even with a five-year visa. If you have never applied for a Schengen visa before, you should not expect to get much more than the duration of the trip you intend to do (and you will have to describe that trip to the consulate, with supporting documentation).

Comment: Beyond that, the procedure should be explained on the relevant consulate's website. There are also many questions about Schengen visas on this site. I can't repeat all that in comments. You need to do a bit of research yourself and ask more focused questions.